# How to RUN plenv/rbenv in Dockerfile?

Tags: perl, docker

I want to use `plenv` to have perl 5.16 in the docker image. `apt-get` only get 5.14.
`plenv` will install perl in `$HOME/.plenv/versions/5.16.2/`, and I need to append some lines into `$HOME/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.plenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(plenv init -)"
```

Then run `plenv shell 5.16.2` to swith to the new version.

But in Dockerfile, I need to write `source $HOME/.profile && plenv shell 5.16.2` everyline before I run some perl commands. docker didn't exec `$HOME/.profile`, is it a no-login shell?

Though I could write such command before every `RUN`, how can I do this in `CMD` line?

Do docker can solve this by some setting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ENTRYPOINT command to prepend something before each executions or you can simply move your .profile within your .bashrc.

Indeed, docker is a no-login shell, it will not run upstart, simply execute the requested process.